# How to limit the number of time a button pressed in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a FPS game and while I was adding jumping physics, I encountered with a problem. It was that each time I pressed space bar, the player's jump height increased. I want the number of times the space bar pressed when the player is on ground limit to 1. This is the code I wrote:-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController controller;
public float moveSpeed;
Vector3 velocity;
public float gravity;
public Transform groundCheck;
public LayerMask groundMask;
public float groundDistance = 0.2f;
bool isGrounded;
public float jumpHeight;
public float jumpButtonPressedNum = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0 )
    {
        velocity.y = 0f;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") == 1)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your player is on ground or not.

```
if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") == 1)
{
    velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this mistake before - you need to use the `isGrounded` bool you made to test if you're grounded, if you are you can jump, but if you're not touching the ground you can't jump (as you're not grounded).